# Ruby "if file not found do" at the top of the script

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have a few rubys file that I am attempting to reduce duplicate code for.  Below is a snippet of a much larger file that conatins a lot of repeditive code.  Is it possible to add to the `if node['platform_version'] =~ /10.0.14393/` section the `not_if { ::File.exist?('C:/programdata/habitat/chef-base/files/missing_GPO_entries_from_patching.flg') }` so that I don't have to have it individually listed under every single registry change?  Something along the lines of `if node = this and flg file not found, then`

```rb
# If OS is 2016
if node['platform_version'] =~ /10.0.14393/
  registry_key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\DataCollection' do
    values [
      { name: 'AllowTelemetry', type: :dword, data: 0x00000000 },
    ]
    action :create_if_missing
    not_if { ::File.exist?('C:/programdata/habitat/chef-base/files/missing_GPO_entries_from_patching.flg') }
  end
end
```

Comment: Regarding `/10.0.14393/` – note that `.` within a regular expression matches _any_ character. To match a literal dot, use `\.` or maybe `node['platform_version'].include?('10.0.14393')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
if node['platform_version'] =~ /10.0.14393/ && !File.exist?('C:/programdata/habitat/chef-base/files/missing_GPO_entries_from_patching.flg')
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use both `not_if` and `only_if` conditions within the same resource block. The resource will get updated based on both conditions.

For example:

```rb
registry_key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\DataCollection' do
  values [
    { name: 'AllowTelemetry', type: :dword, data: 0x00000000 },
  ]
  action :create_if_missing
  not_if { ::File.exist?('C:/programdata/habitat/chef-base/files/missing_GPO_entries_from_patching.flg') }
  # you can also use .include? method as suggested by Stefan in his comment
  only_if { node['platform_version'] == '10.0.19045' }
end
```

Since you have more code that needs to be run conditionally, one option is to move them into a separate recipe (at the simplest), and call that recipe conditionally. For e.g. you could create a `registry.rb`, and call it from `default.rb`:

*Example default.rb*:

```rb
include_recipe 'mycookbook::registry' if node['platform_version'] == '10.0.19045'
```